# Difference between "Mute conversation" and "Turn off chat for x"? - Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, mute

Suppose I'm chatting with Pitter.

What is the difference between "Mute conversation" and "Turn off chat for Pitter" on Facebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Turn off chat for Pitter" means that the chat will not show up in any of your chat interfaces, unless you explicitly open it in one - the conversation will use an "email" like interface where available instead of a "chat like" one.

"Mute conversation" means that you will not be notified of any new messages in it through any interface